# How can I select all checkboxes of one column in an HTML table?

Tags: javascript, html-table

Does anyone knows how can I make a select all checkboxes in a table if I already have a column with checkboxes? I made one but when I click select all it selects all checkboxes from the table. I want to select checkboxes from a single column not all of them.

Comment: Is there anything common about the checkboxes or td's the checkboxes reside in, such a a class?

Comment: @kinakuta. see my update for a scenario where there isn't.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Easy jQuery answer:**

```
$('td.theClass input[type="checkbox"]').prop('checked', true);
```

If you use jQuery version < 1.6:

```
$('td.theClass input[type="checkbox"]').attr('checked', 'checked');
```

This will check only checkboxes under the `<td>` with the class `theClass`.

[**The requested Live DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/jnLQQ/)

Or if you want to select the second column by the index:

```
$('td:nth-child(2)').find('input[type="checkbox"]').prop('checked', true);​
```

[**Live DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/jnLQQ/1/)

Comment: Actually, I think you want `.prop('checked', "checked");`, although that might be just for `.attr()`. Don't recall.

Comment: @ElliotBonneville. No, mine is right, your's isn't. [check the docs](http://api.jquery.com/prop/).

Comment: Oh, that's right, it was for jQuery versions < 1.6. My bad.

Comment: @Elliot, the rule of thumb with `prop()` is that it modifies the underlying DOM property, whereas `attr()` modifies the HTML attribute. Both operations are often equivalent, but boolean attributes requiring the same values as their names is an artifact of HTML, not DOM. In this case, `prop()` takes pure booleans, as the underlying DOM property it modifies.